# How to check if there are subscriptions to a broadcast in turbo rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbo-rails

In my Rails view I’m using `turbo_stream_from` to subscribe to a turbo stream broadcast to display a list of patients:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from :all_patients %>
```

I want this list to be updated when a new patient is created, so I call:

```
constly_method
Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_update_to(:all_patients,...)
```

However, I want to run this code only if there are any clients that are actually subscribed to `:all_patients` at the moment, because this code takes some computing resources. So, I want something like

```
if Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_subscribed?(:all_patients)
  constly_method
  Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_update_to(:all_patients,...)
end
```

Is there any way to check that?

Answer (score 0):

ActionCanble data can be accessed with query. For Example

```
ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: User.find(1)).disconnect
```

Documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActionCable/RemoteConnections.html

It good to play around with the query to solve the problem. (If you will find accurate query. Message me to comment. I will enrich my post with it).
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```rb
<%= turbo_stream_from "channel_name" %> # on one page
<%= turbo_stream_from User.first %>     # on another page
```

*Redis* keeps track of some of it:

```rb
>> redis = Redis.new

# active channels
>> channels = redis.pubsub("channels") 
=> ["Z2lkOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy9Vc2VyLzE", "_action_cable_internal", "channel_name"]

# subscribers, which are ActionCable servers
>> redis.pubsub("numsub", channels)
=> ["Z2lkOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy9Vc2VyLzE", 1, "_action_cable_internal", 1, "channel_name", 1]
```

Number of actual users connected, I don't think matters:

```
>> redis.pubsub("numsub", channels)
=> ["Z2lkOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy9Vc2VyLzE", 0, "_action_cable_internal", 1, "channel_name", 1]
#                                          ^
# if i close user page, ActionCable disconnects from that channel

>> redis.pubsub("channels") 
=> ["_action_cable_internal", "channel_name"]
```

*https://redis.io/commands/pubsub-channels/*

---

This one only works per server [instance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actioncable/lib/action_cable.rb#L50-L53) and gives you the number of streams connected for each channel:

```rb
ActionCable.server.connections.flat_map do |conn|
  conn.subscriptions.send(:subscriptions).values
end.flat_map do |channel|
  # also streams seem to get stuck when code reloads in development
  # count goes up with every code change. must be a bug.
  channel.send(:streams).keys
end.tally
# => {"channel_name"=>4, "Z2lkOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy9Vc2VyLzE"=>1}
```